# How to replace a query string in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following line:

```
<li><%# Eval("Gender").ToString() %></li>
```

which displays the gender of a person:

```
M
```

***OR***

```
F
```

How can I modify so, if it's M, it will display MALE and if it's F, it will display FEMALE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator

```
<li><%# (String)Eval("Gender") == "M" ? "MALE" : "FEMALE" %></li>
```